# Linq average in Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary and want to get the average of attendances from a specific timeframe.
So far I have this working which gives me the numbers of attendances:

```
var vCounts = (from pil in planInfoList
               from s in pil.Value
               where (s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay >= TStart 
                   && s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay <= TEnd)
               select s).Count();
```

The s.CheckInActualUtc is multiple dates.

**How to get the avarage of attendances?**
I have tried this, but this is a no go:

```
var vAverage = from pil in planInfoList
               from s in pil.Value
               where (s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay >= TStart 
                   && s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay <= TEnd)
               group s by s.CheckInActualUtc.DayOfYear into g
               select new { av = g.Average() };
```

Comment: `group s.Value by ...` perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the combined average of the averages per day or just the total average (in which case the group by could be omitted)

Comment: Just a note: Instead of double `from` can you simple as that `planInfoList.Values`

Comment: I want a total average.

Comment: `Average` there is only in numerable types.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you want the average of the number of attendees per day:

```
var vAverage = (from pil in planInfoList
               from s in pil.Value
               where (s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay >= TStart 
                   && s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay <= TEnd)
               group s by s.CheckInActualUtc.DayOfYear into g
               select g.Count()).Average();
```

Comment: I dont want the result per day, but a total average. Your solution also give an error if the result i 0. select g.Count()).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(); will fix that.

Comment: and the average of what field exactly? Unless s itself is a value, that would be something like `(from pil in planInfoList
               from s in pil.Value
               where (s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay >= TStart 
                   && s.CheckInActualUtc.TimeOfDay <= TEnd)
               select s.SomeValue).Average(); `

Comment: or a number of attendences per another group? such as us per attendee? If not this or the above, I don't get what you're after.